# VS2015 14 OpenCV 3.1.0 build stuck

Tags: python, c++, opencv, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I have been using OpenCV 3.1 for Python on Windows for quite a while.

However, now I am forced to do a cmake build for the opencv_contrib modules which do not have a .pyd file.

I am building the entirety of opencv in VS 2015 14.

I had some issues getting it started (running as admin and disabling AV fixed those) but now the build is consistently getting stuck on these two lines:

> 127>  opencv_test_imgproc.vcxproj -> C:\Users\dsjm8\Desktop\BUILD 3\bin\Release\opencv_test_imgproc.exe
>
> 127>  opencv_test_imgproc.vcxproj -> C:/Users/dsjm8/Desktop/BUILD 3/bin/Release/opencv_test_imgproc.pdb (Full PDB)

Has anyone had this issue before? The CPU and disk usage for msbuild and for devenv are both 0 - implying they aren't doing anything.

There are no errors, just these two lines, 0 cpu and disk usage by the related processes and ctrl break does not work (I have to cancel the processes to exit)

Thanks in advance

Comment: no idea why it is stuck, but you could try to disable building of the test programs in CMake (GUI) if you don't need them!

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware that was an option in the cmake. Trying now.

Comment: Eugh now it is stuck on 99>  opencv_tracking.vcxproj -> C:\Users\dsjm8\Desktop\build4\bin\Release\opencv_tracking300.dll

Comment: sorry, no idea there, maybe someone else...

Comment: does it stuck also for "debug" version ?